# Share SharePoint list with Subsite - Permissions issue?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, list, web-part, permissions

I have a list in one site and i am trying to share it with users who have access to the subsite, but do not have access to the parents site where the data in the list is from.

I used the data viewer webpart. I had someone who has permissions to the subsite and not the parent site test it for me and they got the error

> "Onload: Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

I am guessing it is a permissions issue since she does not have access to the list. Is there another way to display a list view of a webpart to a subsite. The key is making it visible to people who do not have permissions to the parent site. Is this even possible? Or, am i frustrating myself trying to figure this out for nothing?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to break permissions inheritance just for that list? And give those people explicit access to the list? That way they would have access to the list and nothing else in that particular site.

Comment: Is it a custom listtemplate? If so, they might not be able to see the template